# CTFD Server -- ctfd-cli bulk challenge import

Tags: ctf

I've built a script that automates the building of a CTFd sever and I've installed the ctfd-cli. I am a bit confused on how exactly I can import all of my challenges into the CTFd server. This was my workflow:

I have a csv with all of the columns possible for a challenge. Each row is a challenge. I created a script called 'csv2yaml.py' which converts those challenges into one yaml with what was described in the format needed for the challenges under [challenge specifications](https://github.com/CTFd/ctfcli/blob/master/ctfcli/spec/challenge-example.yml). I am getting a massive error when I try the following:

`docker exec ${CONTAINER_PREFIX}-ctfd-1 bash -c "cd /opt/ctfcli_project && ctf challenge add /CTFd/embedded_CTFd && ctf challenge install /CTFd/embedded_CTFd"`

that location is where my challenge.yml is. I think I'm confused on this part. Is every challenge supposed to have its own yaml or can I have them all in one yaml file? If so, then is it a formatting issue? If not, How can I possibly go by importing all of my challenges then? Am I to create a directory for every challenge with the challenge name, then have a subdirectory 'Files' and a 'challenge.yml' for each challenge? If that is so, what would the workflow be? Do I have to add that challenge directory to the config file under [challenges] and then import each directory individually? Or can I have one primary directory named "Challenges" and then have the subdirectories for every challenge? Any help would be greatly appreciated.